# How to get the selenium with python script batch execution reports using allure reports

Tags: python, selenium, allure

I have 10 Scripts which got developed using selenium with python. Now i want to run all the 10 Tests at a time and need to get the allure report for all the 10 tests? What is the process? I know about the how to run the test individually and get the report using allure but i dont know the process of running mutliple tests and dont know the process of getting single allure report of multiple test results.

Need command in pycharm editor how to run the mulitiple tests?
Need command in pycharm editor how to get the allure report for mutliple test results?

I know about the how to run the test individually and get the report using allure but i dont know the process of running mutliple tests and dont know the process of getting single allure report of multiple test results.

Comment: Are the 10 scripts totally different or the code is the same except for some parameters which change from script to script?

Comment: 10 Scripts are totally different

Comment: i think you could put each script in a separate file and then with `threading` running them at same time each one in a separate browser window